# Is there another step I am missing with HID gamepads?

Tags: embedded, hid, atmel, gamepad

I am running a ItsyBitsy M0 board with a custom firmware using the ATMEL start (HID GENERIC).

When I run the firmware as default the device shows up in the device manager with no errors. Since its just running the generic hid example nothing more comes from that.

When I run with my own custom report descriptor the device shows up in the device manager but with a yellow exclamation point. (error 10 in input.inf). Since the descriptor was written for a gamepad I was hoping to see it in the gamepad settings screen.

When I look at the packets sent through with wireshark all I see is windows requesting the descriptior and my device responding with my descriptor multiple times... as if windows did not like what it got and asked for it again.

I've looked over the descriptor and cant see what's wrong with it. I'm 90% certain there is something wrong with it though. But also maybe there is something with the underlying USB layer that I need to change to make it a gamepad as well?

Here is my descriptor:
*Edit: In my tiredness I gave you the wrong "more complicated" descriptor. That I intend to use. I will edit it to be more exact in what I want.

```
    0x05, 0x01, //Usage Page (Generic Desktop Ctrls)
    0x09, 0x08, // Usage (Multi Axis)
    0xA1, 0x01, // Collection (Application)
    0x85, 0x01,     //REPORT_ID(1)
    0x05, 0x02,     //Usage Page (Simulation Controls)
    0x15, 0x00,     //LOGICAL_MINIMUM (0)
    0x27, 0xFF,
    0xFF, 0x00,
    0x00,           //LOGICAL_MAXIMUM (65535)
    0x75, 0x10,     // REPORT_SIZE (16)
    0x95, 0x01,     // REPORT_COUNT (1)
    0xA1, 0x00,     //COLLECTION (PHYSICAL)
    0x09, 0xBA,         //USAGE RUDDER
    0x81, 0x02,         //INPUT (Data,Var,Abs)
    0xC0,           //END_COLLECTION (Physical)
    0xC0        //END_COLLECTION (Application)
```

> Did you revert your descriptor to the values of the default? Was the device accepted then?

I did do that and it worked. The problem is that Atmel decided to use the vender specified usage page so the second I try to move that into the generic desktop space I get the same problem. Here is the original example they gave me:

```
0x06, 0xFF, 0xFF,  // Usage Page (Vendor Defined 0xFFFF)
0x09, 0x01,        // Usage (0x01)
0xA1, 0x01,        // Collection (Application)
0x09, 0x02,        //   Usage (0x02)
0x09, 0x03,        //   Usage (0x03)
0x15, 0x00,        //   Logical Minimum (0)
0x26, 0xFF, 0x00,  //   Logical Maximum (255)
0x75, 0x08,        //   Report Size (8)
0x95, 0x40,        //   Report Count (64)
0x81, 0x02,        //   Input (Data,Var,Abs,No Wrap,Linear,Preferred State,No Null Position)
0x09, 0x04,        //   Usage (0x04)
0x09, 0x05,        //   Usage (0x05)
0x15, 0x00,        //   Logical Minimum (0)
0x26, 0xFF, 0x00,  //   Logical Maximum (255)
0x75, 0x08,        //   Report Size (8)
0x95, 0x40,        //   Report Count (64)
0x91, 0x02,        //   Output (Data,Var,Abs,No Wrap,Linear,Preferred State,No Null Position,Non-volatile)
0x09, 0x06,        //   Usage (0x06)
0x09, 0x07,        //   Usage (0x07)
0x15, 0x00,        //   Logical Minimum (0)
0x26, 0xFF, 0x00,  //   Logical Maximum (255)
0x75, 0x08,        //   Report Size (8)
0x95, 0x04,        //   Report Count (4)
0xB1, 0x02,        //   Feature (Data,Var,Abs,No Wrap,Linear,Preferred State,No Null Position,Non-volatile)
0xC0,              // End Collection
```

Hopefully my simpler descriptor, without buttons, may help (or it may just announce a different problem)

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Did you revert your descriptor to the values of the default? Was the device accepted then? (I think so.) Now you can change a single entry after the other to see when Windows begins to stumble. You might want to [edit] your question with your observations.

Comment: @thebusybee I updated with more information. Thanks for taking the time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured this out. For anyone who may have this problem in the future:

In the USB layer there is a HID field in the configuration response that includes the interface descriptors. In there is another field labeled "HID DESCRIPTOR" that describes the length of HID descriptor that will be requested in the future.

Once I found and changed the #define that has that length to match my new report descriptor it worked perfectly.

Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I think it could be an alignment error. This is what I get when I run it through [hidrdd](https://github.com/abend0c1/hidrdd):

```
// All structure fields should be byte-aligned...
#pragma pack(push,1)

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Button Page inputReport (Device --> Host)
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

typedef struct
{
                                                     // No REPORT ID byte
                                                     // Collection: CA:GamePad CP:
  uint8_t  BTN_GamePadButton1 : 1;                   // Usage 0x00090001: Button 1 Primary/trigger, Value = 0 to 1
  uint8_t  BTN_GamePadButton2 : 1;                   // Usage 0x00090002: Button 2 Secondary, Value = 0 to 1
  uint8_t  BTN_GamePadButton3 : 1;                   // Usage 0x00090003: Button 3 Tertiary, Value = 0 to 1
  uint8_t  BTN_GamePadButton4 : 1;                   // Usage 0x00090004: Button 4, Value = 0 to 1
  uint8_t  BTN_GamePadButton5 : 1;                   // Usage 0x00090005: Button 5, Value = 0 to 1
  uint8_t  BTN_GamePadButton6 : 1;                   // Usage 0x00090006: Button 6, Value = 0 to 1
  uint8_t  BTN_GamePadButton7 : 1;                   // Usage 0x00090007: Button 7, Value = 0 to 1
  uint8_t  BTN_GamePadButton8 : 1;                   // Usage 0x00090008: Button 8, Value = 0 to 1
  int16_t  GD_GamePadX;                              // Usage 0x00010030: X, Value = -32767 to 32767 <-- Error: Field not aligned on 16-bit boundary <-- Info: Need 8 padding bits before this field
  int16_t  GD_GamePadY;                              // Usage 0x00010031: Y, Value = -32767 to 32767 <-- Error: Field not aligned on 16-bit boundary <-- Info: Need 8 padding bits before this field
  int16_t  GD_GamePadZ;                              // Usage 0x00010032: Z, Value = -32767 to 32767 <-- Error: Field not aligned on 16-bit boundary <-- Info: Need 8 padding bits before this field
  int16_t  GD_GamePadRz;                             // Usage 0x00010035: Rz, Value = -32767 to 32767 <-- Error: Field not aligned on 16-bit boundary <-- Info: Need 8 padding bits before this field
} inputReport_t;

#pragma pack(pop)
```

Try either adding 8 bits of padding after the buttons, or changing the order so that the 16-bit values appear first in the report descriptor.

Comment: I updated with better information. Thank you for your time.